# Solve for complex roots of polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

My textbook wants to solve for poles of the following polynomial

$$
  \frac{1}{1+(s/j\Omega_c)^{2N}}
$$

A pole will be where

\begin{align*}
  1+(s/j\Omega_c)^{2N} &= 0 \\
  s &= (-1)^{1/2N} j \Omega_c \\
\end{align*}

From there my book says there will be $2N$ poles of the form

\begin{align*}
  s_k &= \Omega_c e^{(j\pi/2N)(2k+N-1)} \\
\end{align*}

for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, 2N-1$.

How do I derive this step from the previous step. If I substitute $-1=e^{j\pi}$ and $j=e^{j\pi/2}$, I get:

\begin{align*}
  s &= \Omega_c \cdot e^{j\pi/2N} e^{j\pi/2} \\
  s &= \Omega_c \cdot e^{(j\pi/2N) (1 + N)} \\
\end{align*}

How do I get from that to the book derived answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start from the elementary stuff: $$ -1 = cos(m\pi)+ i \sin(m\pi)$$ where $m$ can be any odd integer i.e. $m = 2k-1$ where $k \in \mathcal{Z}$. To find, say, $p$-th root of it we write:
$$ (-1)^{1/p} = \left(cos((2k-1)\pi)+ i \sin((2k-1)\pi)\right)^{1/p} = cos((2k-1)\pi/p)+ i \sin((2k-1)\pi/p) = e^{j(2k-1)\pi/p}.$$
To get $p$ different roots we consider $k = 0,1,2,3,\ldots, (p-1)$. It is easy to see that roots will start repeating when we put $k = p$ or $k = p+1$ and so on.
In this problem we have to replace $p$ by $2N$ to get all the possible roots of $-1$ as required in the problem. Thus we have 
$$ (-1)^{1/2N}= e^{j(2k-1)\pi/2N},$$
where $k = 0,1,2,3,\ldots, (2N-1)$, Hence the $s$-value ($s = (-1)^{1/2N} j \Omega_c$), corresponding to $k$-th root will be:
\begin{align*}
s_k & = e^{j(2k-1)\pi/2N} j  \Omega_c \\
& = e^{j(2k-1)\pi/2N} e^{j\pi/2} \Omega_c \\
& = e^{j(2k-1)\pi/2N + jN\pi/2N} \Omega_c \\
& = e^{(j\pi/2N) (2k+N-1)} \Omega_c
\end{align*}
where $k = 0,1,2,3,\ldots, (2N-1)$.